# Post HTML5 using Lemoon CMS

Tags: html, tinymce, lemoon

I am using the Lemoon CMS, and the wysiwyg (tiny_mce) editor is stripping out my HTML5 tags on save. Any way around this? I could possibly inject the HTML on the server side of things, but that completely negates having a CMS in place for that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution online [here](http://ngxo.com/thread/19142928) Simply need to modify the App_Data/Settings/tinymce-standard.js file to include the desired html5 elements in the "extended_valid_elements" variable.